# It is possible to create a GridVIew of LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, gridview

i need to have a gridview of linearlayouts. Each linearLayout must have a imageview and a relativelayout children with more childrens on it.

I'm searching for tutorials/examples of creating gridviews of LinearLayouts but i can't find nothing.

Someone haves a tutorial or can give me some examples or help to do this?

thanks

Comment: It's possible. Just include your layouts in the GridView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and is quite simple indeed.  When you use your GridView, provide an Adapter to it.  In the adapter's `getview` method, you can create any view you like and return it.  For example, you can inflate a view from XML - and that xml may contain a `LinearLayout`.  Alternatively, you can create a linear layout on the fly in that method and add other components to it.

Have a look at this article on Google: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

**Update:** a small example

In your `res/layout/item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="0dip"
     android:paddingBottom="0dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TxtName"
         android:scrollHorizontally="false"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black"
         android:layout_weight="0.2"
         android:padding="2dp"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TxtPackage"
         android:scrollHorizontally="false"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.2"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black"
         android:padding="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get the item corresponding to your position

    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) (convertView == null
               ? LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
               : convertView);
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TxtName)).setText("first text");
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TxtPackage)).setText("second text");
    return row;
}
```

Comment: that tutorial only tell you how to do it with images, but not with linearlayouts. Please, can you give me a little example of doing this with linearlayouts and java code?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 You would go exactly the same way, except your Adapter's `getView` method would return a LinearLayout.  See my edits.

Comment: how can i do it if i want to create the LinearLayout without XML? i'm learning to do it without XML files, Please, what i should change in your code?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 This forum is not the place to get other people to write the code for your for free.  As you stated that you're learning, it would be much useful to just figure the differences out for yourself.  `LinearLayout` is a class.  You can create instances of this class.  You can then create instaces of other Views (TextView, Button, ImageView, etc.) and add them to the LinearLayout.  Search google for "android create ui programmatically" - this should give you what you want.  You'll never learn if you just ask others to do the work for you.

Comment: @Aleks: I'm doing exactly this except that instead of using XML resources, I'm just doing it all in java code. But, the setItemClickListener on the grid view never gets called, the events are never received. I receive the events only if the grid has image views. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Namratha This would depend on what controls you have on your grid elements.  For example, if you have a button, you will need to program its onclick separately.

Comment: I have just an image in the linear layout. (I initially had an image and a checkbox below it but removed the checkbox to see if that was the problem).

Comment: @Namratha If you only have an image, then why do you need a layout?  Just return that ImageView from `getView` method.  If you do have a checkbox, that checkbox needs special handling, just like a button would.

Comment: @Namratha: you can make image view clickable and add listener on it.